# cannot get the whole contents of each row of the array in PHP

Tags: php

I am able to get the first word of each row of the array ($arrayQ). However, I cannot get the rest of the words. That means it jumps to the net row whenever it encouters a space. How can I fix this. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$i=0; 
foreach ($arrayQ as &$value) { 
    $n =$value; ?> 
    <tr> <td align=left > <td align=left><pre>
    <?php 
    echo "<input id='choice' name='arrayQ[]' type='checkbox' value=$n>"; 
    echo $n?>
    </pre></td>&nbsp;&nbsp; </pre> </td> </tr> 
    <?php
```

Comment: <?php
       $i=0;
                            foreach ($arrayQ as &$value) {
        $n =$value;
                        ?>
                    <tr>
      <td align=left >
      <td align=left><pre><?php echo "<input id='choice' name='arrayQ[]' type='checkbox' value=$n>"; echo $n?></pre></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </pre>
      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

Comment: Please add your code in your question!

Comment: Come on... Post this code in your question, not in comments

Comment: Put the `$n` of your `value=$n>";` in quotes

Comment: what is the reason for using $value as a reference?

Comment: Sorry. This is my first time using this website

Comment: i used $value to get the contents of $arrayQ. I only need to get the checked items so I can send them to the back-end

Answer (score 0):

here is a corrected version of your code:

```
<?php
foreach ($arrayQ as $value) {
?> 
    <tr><td align="left">
    <?php 
    echo '<input id="choice" name="arrayQ[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$value.'">'; 
    echo $value;
    ?>
    </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

- I dont know why you used `<pre>` so i removed it.
- I dont know why you closed `</pre>` two times so i removed it.
- I dont know why you used `$value` as a reference so i removed it.
- I dont know why you opened a `<td>` two times so i removed it.
- I dont know why you used `$n` instead of `$value` so i removed it.

If this code continues the first word only printing you should do a

```
print_r($arrayQ);
```

to see if your array is like you expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. Mark Baker, your suggestion works perfectly. I just needed to put $n between quotes.